# Vagrant to automatically clone git repo into specific folder during provision?

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I'm using VCCW: http://vccw.cc/ to have a local wordpress development environment, I need to have a vagrant box as one git repo, and the wordpress installation separately, because of amazon elastic beanstalk, my idea is to have the vagrant box automatically clone the wp installation repo during provision, how can this be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you can do that with simple shell provisioning:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  blablabla

  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "git clone <path to git file>",
    run: "always",
    privileged: "false"
  end
```

Notes:

- you can do `rebase` or `pull` depending if your repo exists or not
- `run: "always"` makes sure this provisioning is run everytime you do `up` or `reload`
- `privileged: "false"` will make sure git is run with your vagrant user, so if you need to update you will not have privileges issue
- you need to make sure `git` is installed on the vm